# Different results in hmac encoding between Dart and PhP

Tags: php, flutter, dart

I'm trying to encode a message in flutter and to verify it with some php code, but somehow there are some differences in the hmac encoding. The header and payload values are the same in both cases. But somehow there are some differences between the resulting values.

Any help would be very helpful, I'm stuck on this for some days now.

```
$base64UrlHeader = 'header';
$base64UrlPayload = 'payload';

$secret = 'secret';
$signature = hash_hmac('sha256', $base64UrlHeader . "." . $base64UrlPayload, $secret, true); // 9b491a7aa29955d9d67e302965665ba0cfa4306c00470f8946eb6aa67f676595
$base64UrlSignature = base64UrlEncode($signature); // sYql52zk6tqYeGSUsDv_219UtgpK3c8-TMuko4n_L5Q

function base64UrlEncode($text) {
  return str_replace(
    ['+', '/', '='],
    ['-', '_', ''],
    base64_encode($text)
  );
}
```

And this is my dart code:

```
// This values are obtained by using the _base64UrlEncode method from below, 
// I just wrote the values directly here not to clutter with code
var base64UrlHeader = 'header';
var base64UrlPayload = 'payload';

/// SIGNATURE
var secret = utf8.encode('secret');
var message = utf8.encode(base64UrlHeader + '.' + base64UrlPayload);

var hmac = new Hmac(sha256, secret);
var digest = hmac.convert(message); // b18aa5e76ce4eada98786494b03bffdb5f54b60a4addcf3e4ccba4a389ff2f94

var signature = _base64UrlEncode(digest.toString()) // YjE4YWE1ZTc2Y2U0ZWFkYTk4Nzg2NDk0YjAzYmZmZGI1ZjU0YjYwYTRhZGRjZjNlNGNjYmE0YTM4OWZmMmY5NA

// This method is used to obtain the header, payload and signature
static String _base64UrlEncode(String text) {
    Codec<String, String> stringToBase64Url = utf8.fuse(base64url);

    return stringToBase64Url
        .encode(text)
        .replaceAll('=', '')
        .replaceAll('+', '-')
        .replaceAll('/', '_');
  }
```

Both the header and payload are obtained from  the same json object,

Comment: Are you sure `$secret` in PHP are UTF-8 encoded?

Comment: No, neither the secret or message are encoded in php. The hash_hmac function in php just takes strings, but in dart I have to encode the values. I did not find another way to hmac encode in dart.

Comment: Strings in PHP are kind of wild when we are talking about charset since there are no rules since they are basically char arrays without any validation. In Dart, all strings are always UTF-16 in memory and you can then convert it to e.g. UTF-8 or other charsets.

Comment: Any way of going around this, to obtain the same results?

Comment: How do you get the value of `secret`? Where does it comes from?

Comment: In flutter I get it from firebase remote config. It's a string value that I get from an API.

Comment: Ok, and in PHP?

Comment: It's a string value generated by the API, Coral Talk: 
https://docs.coralproject.net/coral/v5/integrating/sso/

I just use it as it is in dart.

Comment: I can't really change the php way of getting the secret, I can only work in dart to get the same hmac as the php code gets.

Comment: If you print the secret from Dart, does it contain any special characters?